# My answer was changed from CW now I dont have rep

Tags: support, status-completed, reputation, community-wiki

[My answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/12462/719) was changed from community wiki to regular but I still do not see the rep.

What is the issue?

Comment: For the record, I removed the community wiki status at your request because you said that you'd set it in error.

Comment: @IsaacMoses yes it was. but now there is no rep for it. it is out of CW so i should have the rep ^_^

Comment: I agree. I just wanted to make it clear that the change in status here was deliberate, and the only issue is that the rep change didn't keep up with it.

Answer (score 3):

Reputation generally isn't calculated in real time, so all that was missing was triggering a recalculation of your reputation.

I've done that for you, so you should see a reputation increase corresponding to the 6 upvotes on that answer.

If you want to recalculate your own reputation, you can do so by using the button at the bottom of [this page](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/reputation).